# Change multiple columns to lowercase with dplyr. Difficulty with mutate across everything minus

Tags: r, dplyr, multiple-columns

I want to change multiple columns (in real data approx 20 columns) to lower case. I think it would be easier to select these by excluding those I don't want to change.

Example data:

```
risk = data.frame(title = c("foo", "bar", "blah"),
                  a= c("y", "Y", "n"),
                  b= c("N", "y", "Y"),
                  Summary = rep(NA, 3))
```

**I want to mutate columns 2 and 3 (`a`and `b`)**

I've done it with **base R** but I'd be interested in understanding the dplyr error and in my real data there are many more columns and dplyr would be quicker

**successful base R attempt**

```
risk[,c(2,3)] = lapply(risk[,c(2,3)], tolower)
```

**dplyr attempt (to change everything minus some columns)**

```
 risk = risk%>%
   mutate(across(everything()- risk[,c(1,4)]), ~tolower(.))
```

with resulting error:

```
Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `..1`.
i `..1 = across(everything() - risk[, c(1, 4)])`.
x non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

I've done it with **base R** but I'd be interested in understanding the dplyr error

Comment: `lapply(risk, tolower)` works. To apply to select columns, you could `lapply(risk[,c(1,4)], tolower)`

Comment: ``risk %>% mutate(across(everything(), tolower))``

Comment: @user438383 I don't want to mutate everything. please see clarification in question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to apply it to all columns then this is enough:

```
risk %>% mutate(across(2:3, tolower))
```

Comment: I don't want to mutate all columns. I will clarify in question

Comment: @MarkDavies see edit

Comment: Thanks, though in this case I wanted to exclude specified columns. In real dataset: `risk = risk%>%   mutate(across(-c(1,2,6,7,15,16,21,22,28,29,33,34,35), tolower))`